# 関連付けられてるデータベースの中身が取ってこれない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

### 前提・実現したいこと

Ruby（Ruby on Rails）で食べログのようなレストラン口コミサイトをチュートリアルを参考にしながら作っています。エリアごとにカテゴリを設定しているのですが、これを**検索結果上で**コントローラーから引っ張ってくるのに失敗しています。

### エラーメッセージ

> NoMethodError in Restaurants
>   undefined method `restaurant'

### 該当ソース

・検索結果（restaurants/search.rb）

```
<% @search_restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
 <span><%= space.area.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

・コントローラー（restaurants_controllers.rb）

```
def search
  @restaurants = Restaurant.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @category = Category.all
end
```

・ルーティング（routes.rb）

```
resources :categories, param: :category_name do
  resources :restaurants, only: [:show]
end
```

### 試してきたこと

@categoryを入れてみると、「/restaurants/1」がテキスト表示されました。

すみませんが、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/75231

Answer (score 1):

ビューを下記のように設定したら解決しました。
<%= restaurant.category.try(:name) %>
データベースにカテゴリが入っていないことが問題だったみたいです。